# What is mean by a lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, lambda, expression

Whenever I write below code in netbeans it will highlight the code with yellow lines and tell to use lambda expression, So what is the use of lambda expression in Java?

```
.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
}
}
```

Comment: Are you really going to get a better answer this way than just googling?

Comment: I will try it on google but didn't get a satisfactory answer. @khelwood

Comment: @khelwood you're my favorite

Comment: Then, seriously; you didnt try hard enough. You enter "java lambda" and the first stop you get is the excellent documentation by oracle. It doesn't get much better than that for a newbie who has really no idea about it.

Comment: search lambda functional interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
addActionListener(actionEvent -> System.out.println("Handled by Lambda listener"));
```

you can also do multiline

```
addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
  System.out.println("Handled by Lambda listener");
  System.out.println("something  else");
});
```

Comment: thanks @NimChimpsky